# automatically grab php extension in xampp

Tags: php

i m using xampp

any project that is saved in htdocs is open in `http://localhost/projectname/filename.php`

i want that is there any way to do so when i type

```
http://localhost/projectname/filename and open that page
```

means no need to write .php extension in file( by default extension should be php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mod_rewrite for this. In `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+) $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Then you'll need to edit your httpd config to load mod_rewrite and have `AllowOverride FileInfo`.

Comment: Also, checking the error log will help you figure out what went wrong.

Comment: [Fri Jan 22 19:48:45 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://localhost/project/cms/add_item.php
[Fri Jan 22 19:48:45 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.,referer: http://localhost/project/cms/add_item.php

Comment: Thanks a Lot Dear, it works...
now one last query
if i write something wrong in page name it show 
`500 Internel server error`
but before this htaccess file 
it shown
`404 not found error`

Comment: Thanks Buddy, It works..You are Great
one last query
before this htaccess file, page not found error comes with 
`404 page not found ` 
but now
`500 Internel Server Error`
Occurs ON PAGE NOT FOUND

Comment: Change the second line to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.+\.php`.

Comment: now my all CSS and JS is not working bcoz i have been write conditions of js and css on pages ( with .php) but now it's without .php

Comment: Okay, then you'll need both `RewriteCond` lines in place, one after the other. Order shouldn't matter.